# Redis cache config setting from Springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jedis

Currently we are exploring Redis as distributed in-mem cache which would be hosted on AWS via Amazon elasticache.
For Redis cluster connection from application, we are using Jedis client.
What are the cache property settings supported from client side?
org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration does not give much options other than TTL(time-to-live). IS there any other way to set more cache properties from client-side like enabling ssl, memory size etc.?